# How to change url of posts?

Tags: posts, url-rewriting, query-posts

I want to show my posts url like "domain.in/blogs/blogname" . for only the posts not for the pages. how can i make it like that

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your permalink structure to include "blogs" for posts. Here are the steps to do that:

Go to your WordPress dashboard and click on "Settings" > "Permalinks".
Select the "Custom Structure" radio button.
In the text field, enter "`/blogs/%postname%/`" (without the quotes).
Click the "Save Changes" button.
This will set the permalink structure for your posts to "domain.in/blogs/blogname".